# Some system applications can not connect to the network

Tags: networking, internet, 20.04, ethernet

Applications can not connect to my (wired) network. some examples are: settings, the top bar, software and updates, livepatch, etc. the terminal, firefox and software updater (witch is different than the software and updates app) can connect.

Here is an example screenshot, google loads in firefox, software and updates/livepatch does NOT load, and settings has the error: no internet connection -- connect to set up new online accounts.

[image: example screenshot]

I am running Ubuntu server 20.04 with GNOME desktop environment.